# Отступы в android

Tags: java, android, view

Как сделать отступы в java коде (margin) у view элементов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В коде это делается через `LayoutParams` так:

```
((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)someView.getLayoutParams()).marginBottom = 150;
```

Где класс параметров определяется классом родительского контейнера. Т.е. если целевая вьюха лежит в `LinearLayout`, то кастовать надо к `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. Если в `FrameLayout`, то к `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `LayoutParams`

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
yourbutton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте в xml разметке атрибуты margin, margin-left, margin-right, margin-top, margin-bottom

Comment: Мне нужно через код, причём тут разметка?